# Are Jews allowed to participate in Valentine's Day rituals?

Tags: halacha, christianity, non-jewish-holidays

Are Jews allowed to participate in Valentine's Day rituals? Although St. Valentine's Day is originally a quasi-Christian holiday, it seems that some communities allow participation.* Which communities are these, to what extent do they allow participation, and what is the rationale for allowing it?

*(suggested by [this article](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/holidays/About_Holidays/Non-Jewish_Holidays/Valentines_Day.shtml), which concludes, "...many rabbis allow Jewish participation in Valentine's Day rituals.")

Comment: Adding any information in your possession that led you to ask the question (for instance, your basis for writing "it seems that some communities allow participation") will raise the quality of the question.

Comment: Why should a committed Jew **want** to "participate in Valentine's Day **rituals**"? There are many opportunities to honour our wives witin our own traditions.

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok I'm not saying that any Jew does or does not want to participate in them. It is nonetheless a relevant question about Jewish law and custom.

Comment: @SAH That's great. I agree.

Comment: Rabbi Aryeh Lebowitz spoke about this last week. https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/895500/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/from-the-rabbi-s-desk-valentine-s-day-gift-for-secretary-beracha-on-thousand-dollar-sandwich/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rabbi Michael Broyde discusses the issue in a post [here](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v51/mj_v51i27.html#CGV). One of his major points is "that
Valentine's Day is no longer celebrated even by Christians as a Christian
holiday."

To quote his conclusion:
`I think it is the conduct of the pious to avoid explictly celebrating Valentine's day with a Valentine's day card, although bringing home chocolate, flowers or even jewerly to one's beloved is always a nice idea all year around, including on February 14.`

Answer (score 1):

It is still an official church holiday of several churches such as Anglican, Lutheran, and Eastern Orthodox. Also, some historians have traced the pre-Christian origin of St. Valentines day to the Lupercalia Holiday, which was an ancient Roman pagan holiday complete with sacrifices to idols etc. The mascot of this holiday is Cupid who was a "god" of desire in ancient mythology which is also about Avodah Zarah and should be avoided.- from Wikipedia

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Shemerel. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: This post could be greatly improved by editing in sources that these are actually issues.