St. Patrick’s Day and Chukot Hagoyim
According to Halacha, is the holiday St. Patrick’s Day considered Chukot Hagoyim? So would Jews be prohibited from wearing green or (consensually) pinching somebody not wearing green on that day? What about dressing up like a leprechaun? The reason I ask is because many Poskim give a heter that things celebrated in a secular context aren’t Chukot Hagoyim, even if they are of non-Jewish religious origin.

similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14224/759

Who are these many poskim and what are the criteria for determining something being celebrated in a secular context?

Obviously assur. I heard in the name of Reb Yisroel Belsky.

Thank you for this answer and the quote from Rav Belsky. And welcome to Mi Yodea! The style of this site is such that a bald quote, and saying "obviously assur", isn't the preferred approach. If something is "obvious", an explanation of why it is obvious (e.g. because he was a saint). Similarly, a quote from Rav Belsky zatz"l from an anonymous person on the Internet is not as helpful as an article, book, or website in which he is quoted.
